# Repeat Image in fpdf without creating another instance

Tags: fpdf

I know in PDFs one can have an image repeated (appear in the PDF more than once) without having multiple instance of the image (i.e. the image data appears in the file only once).

Is there a way to do this with fPDF?  I am generating a PDF containing sheets of cards; each has artwork.  The artwork, which can be 300dpi, may appear in the file thousands of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPDF will only embed the image once.

From http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

> Remark: if an image is used several times, only one copy is embedded in the file.

Answer (score 0):

fPDF does this always.  It checks to see if the filename has been added already and creates a reference to the original rather than re-add the image data.

I had used a report designer where this kind of reference had to be made explicitly and I erroneously expected fPDF would work similarly.